# How to find the next non blank cell and print the value in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, nonblank

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to find the date for the next non blank cell based on column B, and print the date in column C.

For example, the next non blank cell after `B3` is `B4`, so the formula will copy the date in cell `A4` to cell `C3`.

Another example, the next non blank cell after `B4` is `B7`, so the formula will copy the date in cell `A7` to cell `C4`

Column E is the expected output for column C.

May I know how to achieve this without using any formula that is only available to office 365 user? Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below array formula for non 365 version of excel.

```
=IFERROR(IF(B3="","",INDEX($A$3:$A$14,SMALL(IF($B$3:$B$14<>"",ROW($A$3:$A$14)-ROW($B$2),""),COUNTA($B$3:$B3)+1))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]